# Como guardar datos en un archivo CSV en python en una sola linea

Tags: python, csv, filewriter

tengo un problema, quiero crear un archivo CSV en Python y escribir nuevos datos en una sola línea, sin que se escriban debajo de ella.

El código que estoy usando es este:

```
totalMavIa = [8]

with open('Phj','w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(totalMavIa)
```

Entonces quiero que cuando meta un nuevo dato, por ejemplo el 10, luego el 15 y así sucesivamente, el archivo CSV aparezca como: "8,10,15".

Si alguien me puede ayudar. Muchas gracias, saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que importar `csv` y en mi caso use solo `write`. Espero que te sirva esta implementación:

```
import csv

totalMavIa = ['36']


with open('Phj.txt', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvfile.write(','.join(totalMavIa))
    csvfile.write(',')
```

Complementando con el comentario que me hiciste, podrias usar esto:

```
import csv
totalMavIa = [36,25,3,4]

# with open('Phj.txt', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
#     csvfile.write(','.join(totalMavIa))
#     csvfile.write(',')
   

with open("Phj.csv", "a+", newline ='') as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
    wr.writerow(totalMavIa)
```

Editando por **tercera vez** este comentario de acuerdo a la retro dada en los comentarios de esta pregunta, adjunto lo siguiente:

```
import csv

totalMavIa = [1,2,3,4,5]

with open("Phj.csv", "a+", newline ='') as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel', delimiter=',', lineterminator=',')
    wr.writerow(totalMavIa)
```

Comment: Pero eso sería para meter un string, en caso de que quiera meter un vector por ejemplo algo = [2,5,6,8,9,7,5,6] y después otro vector algo2 = [5,6,6,8,9,10] me saldría un error, crees que se pueda hacer eso de que yo coloque [algo,algo2.....]

Comment: Hola gracias por la actualización, pero creo que no funciona correctamente ya que me agrega los datos en una nueva fila y lo que quería más bien es que los números se agreguen enseguida de los que ya tenia sin salto de línea

Comment: Ahhh ya entiendo lo que requieres. Te vuelvo a actualizar el comentario. Esto tercero, te debería de servir.